# Wonky quarterly normalization query, needs better eyes. My recursion skills are weak in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am sorry if this is a common question but I can't seem to find a solid solution (without brute forcing it). I am currently running Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio on Windows 7.

I have this table:

[image]

My final query which basically creates the last column on the image is super wonky. I can think of a few ways to deal with this in my native languages (Python, Matlab) but being new to T-SQL, I am having difficulty solving this little bit. The following code gives me rows 13:53 of the final column in my table (posted):

```
{
select ROW_NUMBER() over(ORDER BY F.WEEK_ENDING) AS 'ROW',f.*
INTO #TEMP_13
from #THE_FINAL_COUNTDOWN f

select t.*, "13_week_normalization" = 
    case    
    when t.ROW = 13 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 1 and 13)
    when t.ROW = 14 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 2 and 14)
    when t.ROW = 15 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 3 and 15)
    when t.ROW = 16 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 4 and 16)
    when t.ROW = 17 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 5 and 17)
    when t.ROW = 18 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 6 and 18)
    when t.ROW = 19 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 7 and 19)
    when t.ROW = 20 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 8 and 20)
    when t.ROW = 21 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 9 and 21)
    when t.ROW = 22 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 10 and 22)
    when t.ROW = 23 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 11 and 23)
    when t.ROW = 24 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 12 and 24)
    when t.ROW = 25 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 13 and 25)
    when t.ROW = 26 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 14 and 26)
    when t.ROW = 27 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 15 and 27)
    when t.ROW = 28 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 16 and 28)
    when t.ROW = 29 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 17 and 29)
    when t.ROW = 30 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 18 and 30)
    when t.ROW = 31 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 19 and 31)
    when t.ROW = 32 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 20 and 32)
    when t.ROW = 33 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 21 and 33)
    when t.ROW = 34 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 22 and 34)
    when t.ROW = 35 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 23 and 35)
    when t.ROW = 36 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 24 and 36)
    when t.ROW = 37 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 25 and 37)
    when t.ROW = 38 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 26 and 38)
    when t.ROW = 39 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 27 and 39)
    when t.ROW = 40 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 28 and 40)
    when t.ROW = 41 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 29 and 41)
    when t.ROW = 42 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 30 and 42)
    when t.ROW = 43 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 31 and 43)
    when t.ROW = 44 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 32 and 44)
    when t.ROW = 45 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 33 and 45)
    when t.ROW = 46 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 34 and 46)
    when t.ROW = 47 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 35 and 47)
    when t.ROW = 48 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 36 and 48)
    when t.ROW = 49 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 37 and 49)
    when t.ROW = 50 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 38 and 50)
    when t.ROW = 51 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 39 and 51)
    when t.ROW = 52 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 40 and 52)
    when t.ROW = 53 then (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between 41 and 53)
    else NULL
    end
from #TEMP_13 t
group by t.ROW, t.WEEK_ENDING, t.CalendarWeek, t.TOTAL_USER_RESETS, t.TOTAL_AUTO_RESETS, t.TOTAL_RESETS
        , t.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN, t.USER_AFFECTED, t.AUTO_AFFECTED, t.TOTAL_AFFECTED
ORDER BY t.WEEK_ENDING}
```

I am obtaining the correct result but I HATE having to take this route. I know there is a much more elegant/efficient solution I am just not getting it at the moment.

I appreciate any advice/criticism.

Thank you in advance.

-Stelio

Comment: T-SQL != MySQL, I removed the erroneous tag.

Comment: Thanks, any other input you'd like to provide? :)

Comment: I also formatted the query so people can read it. You're welcome.

Comment: I appreciate it I am a huge noob as you can tell. My apologies

Comment: I can't answer the actual question, I don't know T-SQL. I came here because of the MySQL tag, then saw that it wasn't really about MySQL.

Comment: BUMMER! Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below. You might have to change the precision of the `13_week_normalization` column depending on your data:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(ORDER BY F.WEEK_ENDING) AS 'ROW',
CAST(NULL AS DECIMAL(20,8)) AS '13_week_normalization',
f.*
INTO #TEMP_13
from #THE_FINAL_COUNTDOWN f


UPDATE 
  T1
SET
  [13_week_normalization] = (select SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_RESETS)/SUM(1.0*t2.TOTAL_SEATS_FLOWN) from #TEMP_13 t2 where t2.ROW between (t1.ROW-12) and t1.ROW)
FROM
#TEMP_13 T1
WHERE  
  T1.ROW >= 13

select t.*
from #TEMP_13 t
ORDER BY t.WEEK_ENDING
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much; this is exactly what I needed and will definitely come in handy in the future. I applaud you sir, beautiful work. I just made some slight changes to it but worked great!